# Issues with startAt in orderBy timestamp - Firebase REST API

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im using the Firebase REST API to retrieve data with the GET method, this is the URL im executing:

```javascript
    const url = `https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${projectId}/databases/${dataBase}/documents/${collectionName}/${documentId}?&key=${apiKey}&pageSize=${pageSize}&pageToken=${nextPageToken}&orderBy=timestamp&startAt=${startTime}`;
```

But it return this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"startAt\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'startAt' could not be found in request message.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"startAt\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'startAt' could not be found in request message."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If im omitting the paramemeter of startAt it works fine.

The format of startTime, id try it in all the following ways, and all return the same error:

- Firebase return format: 2022-06-16T15:46:46.061Z
- Unix Timestamp:1655394406
- ISO 8601 date: 2022-06-16T15:46:46+00:00

What im doing wrong?

(For reference [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-filtering) is the official documentation where the startAt is explained)

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the **Firestore** REST API, but are referencing the documentation for the REST API of the Realtime Database. While both products are part of Firebase, they are complete separate - and the API of one cannot be applied to the other.

For the documentation of the **Firestore** REST API, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest

Comment: Thank you, do you know whats the parallel to startAt in Firestore? I see there is an option of StructuredQuery, but I want to continue to use the GET method and just include it in the URL as the orderBy

Comment: As far as I can tell a `Get` requires the full path of the document to read, and doesn't take any query parameters. If the feature you want is only available in a `feedbackStructuredQuery`, that's what you'll have to use.

Comment: Its interesting because in the official documentation there is no mentions to the pageSize, pageToken and orderBy, the other parameters that im using, and they still work.